# Relation with it self in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to relate an entity to itself with GORM 
I tried this:

```
type project struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name     string
    ParentID uint
    projects []project `gorm:"foreignkey:ParentID,association_foreignkey:ID"`
}
```

```
    db.Create(&project{Name: "parent", ParentID: 0})
    db.Create(&project{Name: "child", ParentID: 1})
    db.Create(&project{Name: "child1", ParentID: 1})
```

```
    var project Project
    var projects []Project
    db.First(&project)
    db.Model(&project).Related(&projects)
```

but this is the error:

```
invalid association []
```

My desired result is:

```
{Name:"parent",
    projects:[
        {Name:"child",projects:[]},
        {Name:"child1",projects:[]}
             ]
}
```

and I want to mention that I am new with golang :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `projects` tag to this - `gorm:"foreignkey:ParentID"` and make the field itself public. To get the parent with children in it do:

```
p := &project{}
err := db.Where("name = 'parent'").
          Preload("Projects").
          First(p).Error
```